# iOS SDK - Correct methodology in making connections with an outlet?

Tags: ios, xcode, class, properties, iboutlet

I know that if I use

```
@interface TPN : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIView *testView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
```

I know that the first one is essentially a private variable that is only accessed within the class.  and the second one "@property" is able to be accessed from an instantiated object.  I find it odd in most tutorials that people tend to set properties when they are usually changing an outlet from within the class itself.  Is there any guideline I should be following?

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to specify the ivar at all.  Nor is there a need to use @synthesize.

Use a property, but make sure it is weak, not strong

```
@interface TPN : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
```

In the implementation you can now access the ivar as _testView.

For a private property (above is public) instead put the @property within a category in the implementation file:

```
#import "TPN.h"
@interface TPN ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;   

@end

@implementation TPN
....
```

Comment: how do i make this a public or private property?

Comment: To add to @Khansen this will only work on Xcode 4.5 and above. On older Xcode's you will have to define systhesize and property as strong / retain

Comment: but I think part of the OP's question is, why bother use a property at all, instead of just the instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. If you are only going to use the instance variable inside the class, there is no point to make it a property. A property simply means a pair of getter/setter. If you don't need to do anything specially when getting/setting, you can just use the instance variable directly.

Prior to ARC, there was a side benefit to using properties everywhere, in that it was easier to do memory management for object pointers -- properties declared as `retain` would automatically release and retain for you when you set it, without you typing that code yourself like you would have to do with an instance variable directly. However, now in ARC, the compiler does that for you anyway when you assign, if it's a strong instance variable. So this benefit is now irrelevant.

I would suspect that a lot of the reason people use properties for outlets is because of perpetuation of that usage in almost all tutorials and examples (possibly due to the previous benefit with retain memory management), and they simply don't realize they can do something different.